# how to access the ENTIRE second object of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

i want to access the second object for example? how could i do that? that whol array is under a variable called array. the array itself doesn't have a name though, the same goes to the objects, THANK YOU

```
[ 
{ 
  public_id: 'asdasd', 
  secure_url: 'res.cloudinary.com*****/image/upload/*****/*****.png' 
}, 
{ 
  public_id: 'asdasd', 
  secure_url: 'res.cloudinary.com*****/image/upload/*****/*****.png' 
} 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are indexed by numeric keys, starting with 0. (In other words, the first entry in an array is `array[0]`, so the second is `array[1]`.) That is true no matter the *type* of values in the array.